# LED Stripes with Teensy and Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, led, teensy

I'm currently working on a project to control LED stripes which are connected to a Teensy 3.2 board which is connected to a Windows PC. It is technically based on this project:
https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OctoWS2811.html

There's also a project implemented in vvvv:
https://vvvv.org/contribution/realtime-led-control-with-teensy3.xoctows2811

Both are working fine so far. What I'm trying to do is to port the movie2serial program (regarding the project on pjrc.com) to Python.

So I found this project:
https://github.com/agwn/movie2serial_py

It was not working out of the box, but with a few modifications I got it to run. Here's my code of the class which receives an image, converts it to a byte array and sends it to the serial port:

```
import serial
import numpy as np

class Teensy:
  def __init__(self, port='COM3', baudrate=115200, stripes=4, leds=180):
    self.stripes = stripes
    self.leds = leds
    self.connected = True
    try:
      self.port = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
    except:
      self.connected = False

  def close(self):
    if not self.connected:
      return
    self.black_out()
    self.port.close()

  def send(self, image):
    data = list(self.image2data(image))
    data.insert(0, 0x00)
    data.insert(0, 0x00)
    data.insert(0, ord('*'))
    if not self.connected:
      return
    self.port.write(''.join(chr(b) for b in data).encode())

  def black_out(self):
    self.send(np.zeros((self.leds,self.stripes,3), np.uint8))

  def image2data(self, image):
    buffer = np.zeros((8*self.leds*3), np.uint8)
    byte_count = 0
    order = [1,2,0]
    for led in range(self.leds):
      for channel in range(3):
        for bit in range(8):
          bits_out = 0
          for pin in range(self.stripes):
            if 0x80 >> bit & image[led,pin,order[channel]]:
              bits_out |= 1 << pin
          buffer[byte_count] = bits_out
          byte_count += 1
    return buffer
```

It is working, but it is slow (~ 13 FPS on my computer).

To explain the code: I'm creating a simple animation with cv2 and send the image (numpy ndarray with 4 x 180 pixels, because I have 4 LED stripes with 180 LEDs each) to the send method of the Teensy instance. The send method sends the image to the image2data method to convert the image to a byte array, puts a few bytes at the beginning and sends the whole thing to the Teensy.

There are 2 bottlenecks in this code:

1. Writing to the serial port (self.port.write in method send). Maybe it cannot be speeded up and that's acceptable.

But more importantly:

2. Accessing the image array (image[led,pin,order[channel]] in method image2data). When I change the line to e.g.:

   if 0x80 >> bit & 255:

the code runs 6-7 times faster (~ 80 FPS). By the way, order[channel] is used to convert the color from BGR to GRB.

Long story short: Reading the color from the image array is very slow. How can I speed up the convertion of the image array to a byte array in the method image2data?

When you got to this point, thank you for your patience :-) I'm sorry for the long post, but it is a complex project and not easy to explain for me. I would really appreciate your help, maybe someone else can benefit from this.

Thanks in advance,
Al

Answer (score 0):

That second hotspot can be improved ever-so-slightly by hoisting `order[channel]` outside of that inner loop (by saving `channel_index = order[channel]` inside the loop over `order`), and then writing

```
if 0x80 >> bit & image[led,pin,channel_index]:
```

that'll be a small improvement.  It also looks like hoisting `0x80 >> bit` up level can save that being redundantly calculated 8 times. Save that as `mask` and you'd have

```
if mask & image[led,pin,channel_index]:
```

Together, those might be worth a few FPS.

But looking at your code, something with the way those loops are nested looks amiss. for 180 x 4 RGB LEDs, I'd expect that you'd need to send 180 x 4 x 3 bytes to the Teensy. But the code is sending 3 x 180 x 8. Is there any chance that the two inner loops needs to be inverted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer and your improvements. I'll implement them later, but I guess they will not speed up the framerate to the needed 60 FPS.

The code is sending 3 x 180 x 8 because of the Teensy board. The LEDs are connected to the board with an Ethernet cable which has 8 pins and all 8 pins need to be addressed, otherwise the stripes show weird results. On the other hand in a later configuration I need more than 4 stripes, so currently I don't care to send data to 8 stripes instead of 4. And I don't think the code will run significantly faster.

As I monetioned in my opening post, it seems that this piece of code is very slow and I don't understand why:
image[led,pin,order[channel]]

Here's the code from the Processing sketch which runs at least 10 times faster than the Python script:

```
void image2data(PImage image, byte[] data, boolean layout) {
  int offset = 3;
  int x, y, xbegin, xend, xinc, mask;
  int linesPerPin = image.height / 8;
  int pixel[] = new int[8];
  for (y = 0; y < linesPerPin; y++) {
    if ((y & 1) == (layout ? 0 : 1)) {
      xbegin = 0;
      xend = image.width;
      xinc = 1;
    } else {
      xbegin = image.width - 1;
      xend = -1;
      xinc = -1;
    }
    for (x = xbegin; x != xend; x += xinc) {
      for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        pixel[i] = image.pixels[x + (y + linesPerPin * i) * image.width];
        pixel[i] = colorWiring(pixel[i]);
      }
      for (mask = 0x800000; mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {
        byte b = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
          if ((pixel[i] & mask) != 0) b |= (1 << i);
        }
        data[offset++] = b;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I can't believe that Python is so much slower than Java. I still hope anyone has an idea what's the problem with accessing the pixel of the numpy array.